# How to send a post request to mute a user in web discord? discord proto 1

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm extremely interested in how a user is mutated through a post request to web discord using a post request to the address `discord.com/api/v9/users/@me/settings-proto/1`.
All I found in developer tools is payload settings in encrypted form:

```
'settings': 'ggEdChsJAADATkz4+AQSEAgBFQAAyEIZ3TRHsocBAAA='
```

I attach screenshots and ask for advice to understand how it works

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried to look for at least some crumbs of documentation, but they are not there, and there are no localmute functions for self bot.

Answer (score 0):

Discord does not allow self bots on their platform.